# If string contains certain pattern then do

Tags: r

the following vector is given contaiining names of variables:

```
variables = c("bla_P_blub","bla_K_blib","blo_P_blub","blu_I_blub","bli_K_blub")
```

What I want to do is that if `variables[i]` contains a *K* then do sth if it contains a *P* or *I* then do sth. else.

My approach is the following but it does not work:

```
class_var = 1

if(grep("_K_",variables[i]) > 0){
    class_var = 1
} else{
    class_var = 0
}

if (class_var == 1){

  do sth.

}

if (class_var == 0){

  do sth. else

}
```

The problem is if `variables[i]` contains no *K* then I get the result:

> Error in if (grep("*K*", variables[12]) > 0) { :    argument is of
>   length zero

Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: regex to find the letter between _X_ and then use a switch function to execute your commands

Comment: You could try `med <- grepl("_K_", variables[i]); if (any(med) | sum(med) > 0)`.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex to extract the info you need to trigger the correct function, so in your case it is the `'_X_'`.
Later I would iterate over the vector with the important informations and use a switch.
You can use `{}` within the `switch` to execute more functions then just print or so...

```
variables = c("bla_P_blub","bla_K_blib","blo_P_blub","blu_I_blub","bli_K_blub")

myvars <- sub('.*_([A-Z])_.*', '\\1', variables)
for(myvar in myvars) {
  switch(myvar,
         P=cat('it is a P\n'),
         K={
           cat('it is a K\n')
           cat(sprintf('%s\n',date()))
           },
         cat(sprintf('it was an %s\n', myvar)))
}
```

This returns the following

```
it is a P
it is a K
Fri Jul 17 13:13:51 2015
it is a P
it was an I
it is a K
Fri Jul 17 13:13:51 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix would be to use length, as no matches gives an empty vector:

```
if(length(grep("_K_",variables[i]) > 0)){
```

Answer (score 1):

In r, `grep("K", "YourString")` return a vector of indexes. You need to test the length of `grep("K", variables[12])` using `length(grep("_K_",variables[i])`.

If the length is > 0 then a match was found. Else your variable contains a `K`